# Prove this logarithm equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I keep getting the wrong answer. Can someone please correct my working out

[image]

- a^x=b^(1-x)
- In(a)^x=In(b)^(1-x)
- xIn(a)=(1-x)In(b)
- xIn(a)=In(e)-xIn(b)
- xIn(a)+xIn(b)=In(e)
- x[In(a)+In(b)]=Ine
- x=In(e)/[(In(a)+In(b)]

the correct answer is In(b)/(In(a)+In(b)

Comment: I suppose that $In$ stands for $ln$. If this is the case, please edit.

Answer (score 2):

How have you find $\displaystyle \ln e?$

Applying logarithm wrt $e$ on $\displaystyle a^x=b^{1-x}$

we get
$$ x\ln a=(1-x)\ln b\implies x(\ln a+\ln b)=\ln b$$

Comment: because it said 1-xInb
so the 1 can be re-written like In(e) ??

Comment: @confused, its not $$1-x\ln b,$$ but $$(1-x)\ln b=\ln b -x\cdot \ln b$$

Comment: ohh right.. :D thanks!